# How to effectively siege/capture city in freeciv 1.x?

Tags: freeciv

I have only 6 hours of play so can't say that understand game mechanic at all. It is EXTRA complicated to siege enemy city. I spend 30 offense units in order to break 2 defense unit in city (I try send diplomat to sabotage city but enemy city hold own diplomat, so my attempt fail)!

As say http://freeciv.wikia.com/wiki/Forum:War_against_AI_-_can_it_be_won%3F:

- you attack with less than a full move and lose.
- you move up to their city and stop before you attack and something from the city kills your unit or units.
- if you move a group of units in strategically like a good defense unit with some offensive units, same thing as B only all those units die.

Usually AI city have `Wall` and `Barrack`, so 50% city defense + 50% wall defense + XP restoring from Barrack. One archer can handle a lot of army.

If defender lose all your unit stack die so you can't bring catapult to city (until get advanced with over-square attack). All things against you.

You only can get advantage from navy attack as seems it never kill your ship.

How to effectively siege/capture city in freeciv 1.x?

Comment: I have only 6 hours of play so can't say that understand game mechanic at all. It is EXTRA complicated to siege enemy city. I spend 30 offense units in order to break 2 defense unit in city!

Comment: you need units that have multi move, that allows you to move and attack on the same turn.

Comment: @spartacus `Attack` parameter reduced to 1/3 or 2/3 value if unit already made move... So I must triple my army to use this technique... ((